# Alternative reading of 額

Tags: readings, song-lyrics

In [無情のスキャッツ from 人間椅子](https://youtu.be/CbI79e5iZKs), there's the following line, around 2'41":

> 私の額{ぬか}にも微笑をくれ

The furigana are from the video's subtitles, which are **not** automatically generated by Youtube, so this is definitely intended by the authors.

I couldn't find any reference confirming that `額` had any readings other than `ひたい` and `がく`.
Also, I thought it could be a play on word (1) of some kind, but I couldn't find any word that reads `ぬか` that would make any sense.

What could be the meaning of reading `額` `ぬか` in this context?

---

(1)  *You know, that thing when you attach totally different furigana to a word to express the true meaning of that word in a context, like `地球{ここ}`, but I forgot how it's called*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ぬか is an old-fashioned reading of 額, which is commonly ひたい today. That information is pretty easy to find if you type in both 額 and ぬか in a search engine.

At the bottom I believe you're talking about 当て字(ateji), but that is not relevant to the 額 question.

Comment: Ah. I just didn't find it in my dictionary so I thought, let's just ask... I'll look it up next time. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Interestingly enough, that reading is actually still present in 額ずく